# Is it possible to make a compile-time evaluated function return a different type than the runtime evaluation of the same function?

Tags: c++, constexpr, consteval

Is it possible, at compile time, to determine if a call to a function (a constexpr function mainly) is compile-time evaluated and than just make another version of that function (like what a template does) with a different return type than the original runtime evaluated version ? How ?

```
constexpr decltype(auto) F(int n)
{
    if consteval
    {
        return (int)3;
    }

    else
    {
        return (char)'c';
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    cout << typeid(decltype(F(4))).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid(decltype(F(n))).name() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

error (gcc 12.2) : "inconsistent deduction for auto return type: 'int' and then 'char'"

Using `if constexpr` doesn't give this error, because I think it just "deletes" a section of code (if it is false, the "if" section, otherwise the "else" section). But why doesn't `if consteval` do the same thing ?
Is there an other way to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need something like that ? what's the actual problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: I don't believe that is possible.  The workarounds to make it possible would not comply with the given requirements / constraints.

Comment: Just return different `variant<int, char>` objects.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible. `consteval` if statements (besides their effect on `consteval` function calls) are essentially equivalent to:

```cpp
if (std::is_constant_evaluated())   // if consteval
if (!std::is_constant_evaluated())) // if !consteval
```

The reason why `constexpr` if statements can influece return type deduction is that they turn the false branch into a *discarded statement*, making it as if you hadn't written that code at all.

A `consteval` if statement is simply not going to execute one of the two branches, just like a regular if statement.

#### Possible Solution

```cpp
#include <concepts>

struct wrapper {
    int x;
    wrapper(int x) : x(x) {}
};

consteval int f(std::convertible_to<int> auto&&) {
    return 1;
}

// Will lose in overload resolution to the function above
// because the conversion sequence is longer.
char f(wrapper) {
    return char(0);
}

int main() {
    return f(123);
}
```

With this solution, you have two separate functions, but you call them with the same name because they are overloads of each other.
It is a bit more powerful than just using `if consteval` inside a function though, because any call to `f` is going to be constant-evaluated if possible, even in cases where it's otherwise not required.